# Rails where condition using NOT NIL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, arel

Using the rails 3 style how would I write the opposite of:

```
Foo.includes(:bar).where(:bars=>{:id=>nil})
```

I want to find where id is NOT nil.  I tried:

```
Foo.includes(:bar).where(:bars=>{:id=>!nil}).to_sql
```

But that returns:

```
=> "SELECT     \"foos\".* FROM       \"foos\"  WHERE  (\"bars\".\"id\" = 1)"
```

That's definitely not what I need, and almost seems like a bug in ARel.

Comment: `!nil` evaluates to `true` in Ruby, and ARel translates `true` to `1` in a SQL query. So the generated query is in fact what you asked for - this was not an ARel bug.

Answer (score 567, accepted):

#### Rails 4+

ActiveRecord 4.0 and above adds [`where.not`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions) so you can do this:

```
Foo.includes(:bar).where.not('bars.id' => nil)
Foo.includes(:bar).where.not(bars: { id: nil })
```

When working with scopes between tables, I prefer to leverage [`merge`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) so that I can use existing scopes more easily.

```
Foo.includes(:bar).merge(Bar.where.not(id: nil))
```

Also, since [`includes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) does not always choose a join strategy, you should use [`references`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-references) here as well, otherwise you may end up with invalid SQL.

```
Foo.includes(:bar)
   .references(:bar)
   .merge(Bar.where.not(id: nil))
```

#### Rails 3

The canonical way to do this with Rails 3:

```
Foo.includes(:bar).where("bars.id IS NOT NULL")
```

Comment: Last one here isn't working for me, do we need an extra gem or plugin for this? I get: `rails undefined method 'not_eq' for :confirmed_at:Symbol`..

Comment: @Tim Yes, the MetaWhere gem I linked above.

Comment: @oreoshake MetaWhere/Squeel are well worth having, this is just a tiny facet. But of course a general case is good to know.

Comment: Hi Adam/everyone, do you need both squeel and metawhere to do that nice "ruby only" stuff or is one of them enough? What's the difference, really?

Comment: And another thing: I have not managed to do this with sqlite3. sqlite3 wants to see `field_name != 'NULL'`.

Comment: @mjnissim MetaWhere was created for Rails 3.0, Squeel replaced it for Rails >= 3.1

Comment: I personally try to avoid EVER having raw SQL in my code, so I use Squeel and also the new Arel syntax as explained by Ryan Bigg below

Comment: @jaydel the problem with Squeel is that it needs constant attention to deal with breaking changes, and it doesn't always have an owner. I'm transitioning more toward lightweight Arel helpers and query objects instead.

Comment: @AdamLassek You can really say "it doesn't always have an owner" to most gems in the ruby world. I think that most of us decide to either trust a gem (to a degree) or accept the risk that you might have to fork and fix things you need.

Comment: @AdamLassek thank you Adam. What if there are multiple where conditions? would appending the rest of them .where( other conditions here) not hamper performance?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Chaining `where` conditions is simply building an AST, it doesn't hit the database until you hit a terminal method like `each` or `to_a`. Building the query isn't a performance concern; what you're requesting from the database is.

Answer (score 255):

It's not a bug in ARel, it's a bug in your logic.

What you want here is:

```
Foo.includes(:bar).where(Bar.arel_table[:id].not_eq(nil))
```

Comment: I'm curious what the logic is then for turning !nil into '1'

Comment: At a guess, !nil returns `true`, which is a boolean. `:id => true` gets you `id = 1` in SQLese.

Comment: This is a good way to avoid writing raw sql fragments. The syntax isn't as concise as Squeel though.

Comment: I have not managed to do this with sqlite3. sqlite3 wants to see `field_name != 'NULL'`.

Comment: @zetetic Unless you're using postgres, in which case you get `id = 't'` :)

Comment: The problem with this is that it != null always tests true in SQL even if it IS null. Yes, the rails folks have worked around this but using the not_eq syntax just encourages confusion when you eventually do need to do the conversion to SQL.

Comment: Worth noting that this works in Rails 3 (unlike several answers).

Answer (score 48):

Not sure of this is helpful but this what worked for me in Rails 4

```
Foo.where.not(bar: nil)
```

Comment: This is the best answer here. -- 2017 https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activerecords-wherenot

Answer (score 38):

For Rails4:

So, what you're wanting is an inner join, so you really should just use the joins predicate:

```
  Foo.joins(:bar)

  Select * from Foo Inner Join Bars ...
```

But, for the record, if you want a "NOT NULL" condition simply use the not predicate:

```
Foo.includes(:bar).where.not(bars: {id: nil})

Select * from Foo Left Outer Join Bars on .. WHERE bars.id IS NOT NULL
```

Note that this syntax reports a deprecation (it talks about a string SQL snippet, but I guess the hash condition is changed to string in the parser?), so be sure to add the references to the end:

```
Foo.includes(:bar).where.not(bars: {id: nil}).references(:bar)
```

> DEPRECATION WARNING: It looks like you are eager loading table(s) (one
>   of: ....) that are referenced in a string SQL snippet. For example:
>
> ```
> Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'foo'")
> ```
>
> Currently, Active Record recognizes the table in the string, and knows
>   to JOIN the comments table to the query, rather than loading comments
>   in a separate query. However, doing this without writing a full-blown
>   SQL parser is inherently flawed. Since we don't want to write an SQL
>   parser, we are removing this functionality. From now on, you must
>   explicitly tell Active Record when you are referencing a table from a
>   string:
>
> ```
> Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'foo'").references(:comments)
> ```

Comment: The `references` call helped me!

Answer (score 23):

With Rails 4 it's easy:

```
 Foo.includes(:bar).where.not(bars: {id: nil})
```

See also: 
    http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions