# Arel query through an association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

Here are my models:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :registrations, :class_name => "PlayerRegistration"
end

class PlayerRegistration < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :player

   belongs_to :payment

   def self.paid
     where("payment_id IS NOT NULL")
   end

   def self.unpaid
     where(:payment_id => nil)
   end
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :registrations, :class_name => "PlayerRegistration"
end
```

What I would like to do is create a scope on Player that returns all players who have an unpaid registration, so something like:

BAD PSUEDO CODE AHEAD

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.paid
    registrations.unpaid  #But actually return the players
  end
end
```

Is this possible?  It must be, considering that all the data I need is out there, I just have no idea how to write that sort of an AREL query.  Can anybody help?

FWIW I've tried this:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.paid
    includes(:registrations).where("registrations.payment_id IS NOT NULL")
  end
end
```

but that provides me with the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PGError: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "registrations"
   LINE 1: ...registrations"."player_id" = "players"."id" WHERE "registrat...
                                                                ^
   : SELECT "players"."id" AS t0_r0, "players"."first_name" AS t0_r1, "players"."last_name" AS t0_r2, "players"."birthday" AS t0_r3, "players"."gender" AS t0_r4, "players"."created_at" AS t0_r5, "players"."updated_at" AS t0_r6, "players"."user_id" AS t0_r7, "player_registrations"."id" AS t1_r0, "player_registrations"."player_id" AS t1_r1, "player_registrations"."grade_id" AS t1_r2, "player_registrations"."shirt_size_id" AS t1_r3, "player_registrations"."division_id" AS t1_r4, "player_registrations"."coach_request" AS t1_r5, "player_registrations"."buddy_request" AS t1_r6, "player_registrations"."created_at" AS t1_r7, "player_registrations"."updated_at" AS t1_r8, "player_registrations"."league_id" AS t1_r9, "player_registrations"."season_id" AS t1_r10, "player_registrations"."school_id" AS t1_r11, "player_registrations"."payment_id" AS t1_r12 FROM "players" LEFT OUTER JOIN "player_registrations" ON "player_registrations"."player_id" = "players"."id" WHERE "registrations"."payment_id" IS NULL
```

Could anyone show me a better way?  Isn't there a way I can use the paid scope that I already have in PlayerRegistrations?

Comment: Side note, use [scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope) instead of those paid/unpaid functions: `scope :paid where("payment_id IS NOT NULL")` You can also refer to [rail 3 where condition using NOT NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252349/rail-3-where-condition-using-not-null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the real table name in the where() filter:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.paid
    includes(:registrations).where("player_registrations.payment_id IS NOT NULL")
  end
end
```

Comment: +1. I wish I could give more! Your answer was the final hint that helped me answer my own question. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470782/how-can-i-create-a-scope-in-a-model-that-returns-only-those-objects-with-an-asso

Answer (score 1):

You could write:

```
class Player

  scope :unpaid, includes(:registrations).where("player_registrations.payment_id is null")
  scope :paid, includes(:registrations).where("player_registrations.payment_id is not null")

end
```

and now `Player.unpaid` will return all players with unpaid registrations.

If you write something like:

```
class Registration

  scope :paid, where("payment_id IS NOT NULL")
  scope :unpaid, where("payment_id is null")

end
```

then it is possible to write `player1.registrations.unpaid`, but that is not what you want. 
If I understand correctly, you want to find *all players* with unpaid registrations, and that is only possible using the scope on the `Player` class.

Hope this helps.