# How can I create a scope in a model that returns only those objects with an associated rank greater than the current_user's rank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, arel

I am trying to create a `:readable` scope in my `Page` model to return all the `Pages` that the `current_person` has sufficient 'rank' to read:

```
scope :readable, lambda { |current_person| joins(:role_readable)
    .where(:role_readable[:rank].gte(current_person.roles.first.rank) ) }
```

I've tried many scope permutations, including this one, with no success (the one above gives a "can't convert Symbol into Integer" error).

The problem is made more complex because `Users` (which handle authentication etc. / synonymous with accounts) have_many `People`, which represent the `User`'s presence in an organization — ie. a `User` could be a member of multiple organizations, but only needs one way of logging in...

The `Roles` that a `User's` `People` has_many of, give the rank that the scope uses to return the `:readable` pages. (ie. `Users` handle authentication, whereas `People` handle authorization (among other things), as a `User` could be a member of multiple organizations for which the user has different `Roles`, and thus heirarchy and privilege.)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :people
  has_many :roles, through: :people    

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  #  name       :string(255)
  #  rank       :integer 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :people

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role_readable, class_name: "Role", foreign_key: :role_read_id
  belongs_to :role_editable, class_name: "Role", foreign_key: :role_write_id
```

Roles have a hierarchy (eg. Boss, Manager, Worker...) recorded as a `rank` (integer) — the lower the integer the greater the hierarchy (and thus privilege). If any one of the Person's `Roles` has a rank less than or equal to the `:role_readable` of a `Page` then the user has privilege to view the page.

Eg. a `Person` with a `Manager` role could view all pages with a `:role_readable` of `Manager` or `Worker`, but not `Boss`. I need a scope that lists all such readable pages.

`Roles` have a default_scope that ensures they are returned in ascending order of rank, so `role.first` for a `Person` will return the role with the greatest hierarchy (ie. lowest rank value).

I'm using Rails 3.2 and Postgres 9.2.2.0, so am also confusing myself with the many query / Arel options available.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

If I try this scope:

```
scope :readable, lambda { |current_person| where("role_readable.rank
  => ?",current_person.roles.first.rank) }
```

I get this error:

```
PGError: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "role_readable"
LINE 1: ...*) FROM "pages"  WHERE "pages"."team_id" = 2 AND (role_reada...
                                                         ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "pages"  WHERE "pages"."team_id" = 2 AND (role_readable.rank => 1)
```

I'm not sure what to make of the 'missing FROM-clause'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the answer is quite simple, after much experimenting:

```
scope :readable, lambda { |current_person| joins(:role_readable)
      .where(["roles.rank >= ?", current_person.roles.first.rank]) }
```

Although the *join* refers to the association name `:role_readable`, the *where* must use the table name — ie. `roles.rank` not `role_readable.rank`.

A trap for new players? Apparently.

Kudos to [ctcherry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10322/ctcherry) and his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5808706/59195) which gave the game away.