# ActiveRecord IS NOT NULL sql finder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

The following finder prints out `IS NULL`.

```
User.where(:id =>nil) #=> []
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

But I couldn't find how to print out `IS NOT NULL` one?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252349/rail-3-where-condition-using-not-null

Comment: This question has your answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252349/rail-3-where-condition-using-not-null

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The simplest, idiomatic ActiveRecord solution:

```
User.where.not(id: nil)
```

Comment: Note: Only works with 'rails >= v4.0.2'. See: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain/not

Answer (score 26):

Try `User.where("id IS NOT NULL")`

This should do your job

Answer (score 5):

`User.where.not(id: nil)` will work for rails 4.

`User.where("id IS NOT NULL")` will work for older versions.

Comment: This is more or less the same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/27613775/38765 (though you answered first), and also doesn't work on Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4

you can try this

```
User.where("id is not NULL")
```

Also if you are looking to exclude particular id and include nil values following will work

```
User.where("id is NULL or id != 'excluded_id'")
```