# Check date is not null ? (rails, arel)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, arel

How do you check in Rails3 (with or without Arel) if a date is filled in (as in, not null)? I know you can do it by using:

```
obj.where('PLANNED IS NOT NULL')
```

but is it possible without using SQL?

```
// SQL 
SELECT * FROM projecttasks WHERE planned IS not null
```

I tried:

```
# all tasks which have a date
tasks = Projecttask.where(:planned => !nil)
```

or

```
# all task with no planned date (sql: is null)
Projecttask.where(:planned => nil)
```

But that doesn't work. In general, how you can do a 'where' on NULL and NON NULL columns.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [rail 3 where condition using NOT NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252349/rail-3-where-condition-using-not-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check this similar question for the answer.  The answer by Ryan Bigg is what I'm guessing you are looking for.

[Rails where condition using NOT NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252349/rail-3-where-condition-using-not-null)

Comment: Thats, thanks! So you get: Projecttask.where(Projecttask.arel_table[:planned].not_eq(nil)).to_sql

Answer (score 12):

From Rails 4, there's ActiveRecord's [`where.not`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-not).

```rb
User.where.not(name: nil)
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE name IS NOT NULL
```

Until Rails 3 you'd need to use an SQL string: `User.where('name IS NOT NULL')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very fluent in ActiveRecord since I mostly use Mongoid, but I think you can find your answers here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions

I guess you have to use string conditions, as in `where("planned is not null")`

Comment: yeah sorry i will change my question, i wanted it without the SQL way (this is basically a bit of SQL you inject).

Comment: With what I read in the guide page, I don't see any mention of it, so it might not be possible.