# Rails 3 - Create a scope that takes advantage of a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, named-scope

In my model I would like to create a scope that **takes advantage of a method** that is also in my model.

I have the following model method:

```
  def is_paired
    ! pairing_id.nil?
  end
```

I would like to make a scope that looks something like this

```
  scope :paired, where(:is_paired => true)
```

But when I do I get an error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: participants.is_paired: SELECT "participants".* F...
```

How can I create a scope that **takes advantage of a method** in my model???

Comment: The following code works similar to scope. However, it returns an Array rather than an ActiveRecord::Relation. 
def self.paired self.all.find_all{|item| item.is_paired} end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Basically methods used in scopes like `where`, `order` ect. are "translated" to sql queries. Rails doesn't know how to translate custom methods to sql queries.
Anyway you can use the following approach: `scope :paired, where('pairing_id IS NOT NULL')`
For more details you can check: [Rails where condition using NOT NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252349/rail-3-where-condition-using-not-null)

Comment: Thank you... your answer clarified things for me.