# Rails 3: Finding records with datetime 3 days from today

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following Scope:

```
def coming_up_on_renewal(product_name = "product_name")
  where('billing_start_date = NOW() + INTERVAL 3 day AND status = ? AND product_name = ? AND auth_net_subscription_id IS NOT NULL', :active, "#{product_name}")
end
```

And I have manipulated a single record in my database to be 3 days in the future, yet when I run this scope, an empty array is returned.

I am basically trying to retrieve records where the `billing_start_date` is 3 days from the current day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a try with this.

```
def coming_up_on_renewal(product_name)
  where(:status => :active, :product_name => product_name)
  .where(:billing_start_date => 
   (3.days.from_now.beginning_of_day)..(3.days.from_now.end_of_day))
  .where('auth_net_subscription_id IS NOT NULL')
end
```

For your additional "IS NOT NULL" condition see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252349/rail-3-where-condition-using-not-null).

Comment: Im getting an error when running your activerecord statement: `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tASSOC
...name, 'billing_start_date = ?', 3.days.from_now)`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to get it with the following: `where(:status => :active, :product_name => product_name, :billing_start_date => (Time.now.midnight + 3.day)..(Time.now.end_of_day + 3.day)).where('auth_net_subscription_id IS NOT NULL')`

Comment: I've edited my answer, though I am not happy with the `billing_start_date` part. With `3.days.from_now` it's looking for records with exactly that timestamp, down to the second. You might look more for a date range.

Comment: I changed my scope to match your latest edit... works perfectly!

Comment: And now included your feedback. Thanks.