# Rails .where() attribute IS NOT NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I have a `Page` model containing many `Section` models which is associated with a `SectionRevision` through `current_revision`. From the `Page` model I am trying to select all `Sections` where the `current_revision.parent_section_id` is not nil.

`Section` model:

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
  has_many :revisions, :class_name => 'SectionRevision', :foreign_key => 'section_id'
  has_many :references

  has_many :revisions, :class_name => 'SectionRevision', 
                       :foreign_key => 'section_id'
  belongs_to :current_revision, :class_name => 'SectionRevision', :foreign_key => 'current_revision_id'

  delegate :position, to: :current_revision

  def set_current_revision
    self.current_revision = self.revisions.order('created_at DESC').first
  end

  def children
    Section.includes(:current_revision).where(:section_revisions => {:parent_section_id => self.id})
  end
end
```

And `Page` model:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Page', :foreign_key => 'parent_page_id'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Page', :foreign_key => 'parent_page_id'
  belongs_to :page_image, :class_name => 'Image', :foreign_key => 'page_image_id'
  has_many :sections

  validates_uniqueness_of :title, :case_sensitive => false

  def top_level_sections
    self.sections.includes(:current_revision).where(:section_revisions => {:parent_section_id => "IS NOT NULL"})
  end

end
```

---

`Page.top_level_sections` is written based on: [Rails where condition using NOT NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252349/rail-3-where-condition-using-not-null) and currently produces an empty array. It doesn't correctly detect if "parent_section_id" is not null.

How do i write `Page.top_level_sections` correctly?

Comment: What is the intent of `Page.top_level_sections` ? Is it trying to find sections that have no revisions?

Comment: Trying to find sections where current_revision.parent_section_id is not nil.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.sections.includes(:current_revision).
  where("section_revisions.parent_secti‌​on_id IS NOT NULL")
```

Comment: On newer versions of AR: `sections.includes(:current_revision).where.not(section_revisions: {parent_section_id: nil})`