# Rails .where multiple values, one not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This Code pulls records where foobar is Nil

```
Model.where(user_id: 14, foobar: nil)
```

How can I use the same Syntax and get NOT nil?

Something like:

```
Model.where(user_id: 14, foobar: !nil)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3 where condition using NOT NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252349/rails-3-where-condition-using-not-null)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Model.where(user_id: 14).where("foobar IS NOT NULL")

Model.where("user_id = ? AND foobar IS NOT ?", 14, nil)
```

Comment: Thank you this fits what I was looking for. (with rails 3)
Nice Solution

Answer (score 14):

Rails 4:

```
Model.where(user_id: 14).where().not(foobar: nil)
```

Rails 3 - [Rails where condition using NOT NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252349/rails-3-where-condition-using-not-null)

Comment: getting an errror with that ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Comment: Rails version..? also try with `where()` in the second where

Comment: 3.2, the above code still gives me the Argument Error

Comment: @emaillenin hi thank you - question: is there not a performance hit when appending multiple .where() together?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon No they are going to end up as a single SQL query anyway