# Rails Query nil problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to get all the coupons with an expirationDate(date type) that are nil:

```
  @coupons = @deal.coupons.all 
  @coupons = @coupons.where("expirationDate = ?", nil)
```

But for some reason the code above doesn't work. **However**, if instead I do:

```
@coupons = @deal.coupons.all
@coupons = @coupons.where(expirationDate: nil)
```

It gets all the nil coupons as I want it to. I'm confused as to why the first one doesn't work, but the second one does. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL query for `NULL` or `NOT NULL` is as following:

`expirationDate IS NULL` or `expirationDate IS NOT NULL`

It doesn't work with equal "=" sign. You can't do in SQL as 
`expirationDate = NULL`

You could try like this as well

```
@coupons = @coupons.where("expirationDate IS NULL")
```

You can take a look at this answer for other alternatives of using `null` in condition https://stackoverflow.com/a/4252615/343679

Answer (score 3):

for exampel.

```
User.where("name = ?",nil)
```

sql output :

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (name = NULL)
```

The other format:

```
u = User.where(name: nil)
```

sql output:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."name" IS NULL
```

You will find the sql different. Detail for [SQL is null and = null [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)