# What rails console command can be used to query all the users whom has a home_state value in a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need a rails command that can query all the users who has a value in home_state. I have tried to use:

```
User.where('home_state')
```

but couldn't retrieve any information from it.

Comment: User.where.not(home_state: nil)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails where condition using NOT NIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252349/rails-where-condition-using-not-nil)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for all users that do not have nil as a value for home_state, you can use User.where.not(home_state: nil)

Answer (score 1):

You can use
User.where.not(home_state: nil)